# why i am geting these lines on output GAN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on a model for underwater image enhancement. It's my first time on GAN. I am not getting why there are lines on my output of the generator model.
Also, can you suggest to me how to improve the performance of my model?

```py
model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same',input_shape=(256,256,3)))
output=(model.layers)[-1].output
output_=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(output) 

output1=Conv2D(128,(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(output_) 
output3=BatchNormalization()(output1)
output4=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(output3)

layer1=Conv2D(64,(5,5),padding='same')(output4) 
layer1=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer1) 

layer2=Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(output4) 
layer2=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer2) 

next=tf.keras.layers.concatenate([output4,layer1, layer2], axis = 3) 

layer3=Conv2D(128,(5,5),padding='same')(next) 
layer3=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer3) 

layer4=Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same')(next) 
layer4=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer4)

layer5=Conv2D(128,(1,1),padding='same')(output4) 

next1=tf.keras.layers.concatenate([output4,layer3,layer4, layer5], axis = 3) 
next1=Conv2D(128,(1,1))(next1) 
next1=LeakyReLU(0.2)(next1)

output5=Add()([output4,next1])

layer1=Conv2D(64,(5,5),padding='same')(output5) 
layer1=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer1) 

layer2=Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(output5) 
layer2=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer2) 

next=tf.keras.layers.concatenate([output5,layer1, layer2], axis = 3) 

layer3=Conv2D(128,(5,5),padding='same')(next) 
layer3=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer3) 

layer4=Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same')(next) 
layer4=LeakyReLU(0.2)(layer4)

layer5=Conv2D(128,(1,1),padding='same')(output5) 

next2=tf.keras.layers.concatenate([output5,layer3,layer4, layer5], axis = 3) 
next2=Conv2D(128,(1,1))(next2) 
next2=LeakyReLU(0.2)(next2)

output6=Add()([output4,output5,next2]) 

transpose1=Conv2DTranspose(64,(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(output6)
transpose1=BatchNormalization()(transpose1)
transpose1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(transpose1)

transpose2=Add()([transpose1,output]) 
transpose2=Conv2DTranspose(3,(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same',activation='tanh')(transpose2) 

gen=Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = transpose2)
```

**input image**

https://github.com/sachin327/images/blob/main/input_image.png

**image I want to generate**

https://github.com/sachin327/images/blob/main/to_be_generate.png

**generated_image**

https://github.com/sachin327/images/blob/main/generated_image.png

Comment: This could be interesting for you: https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/